# How to replace text in a link across multiple google sheets in the same workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to replace all occurrences of specific text with another text using google script. I want to use a script so that I don't have to manually type each time I want to replace.

This is what I have tried. The script doesn't throw any errors so I'm not sure why it's not working. I want the script to replace the text `example` inside the links that look like this `example.com/this-is-a-link` to `example2.com/this-is-a-link`. I am replacing the text across multiple sheets.

Here is what I have tried.

```
function rePlace() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("a1:a10000");
  var data  = range.getValues();

  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace('/.*example.*/', 'example2');
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, `replace('/.*example.*/', 'example2')` is required to be modified as follows.

#### From

```
data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace('/.*example.*/', 'example2');
```

#### To:

```
data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace('example', 'example2');
```

or

```
data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(/example.com\//, 'example2.com/');
```

By this, `example.com/this-is-a-link` is modified to `example2.com/this-is-a-link`.

In your situation, as other method, how about using TextFinder? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows. When TextFinder is used, I think that the process cost will be lower than that of current script.

#### Modified script:

```
function rePlace() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("a1:a10000");
  range.createTextFinder("example").replaceAllWith("example2");  // Added
}
```

or

```
function rePlace() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("a1:a10000");
  range.createTextFinder("example.com/").useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith("example2.com/");  // Added
}
```

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

### Added 1:

When you want to use above script for several sheets in the active Google Spreadsheet, how about the following script?

#### Sample script:

In this script, the range of `a1:a10000` in all sheets is used.

```
SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheets()
  .forEach(sheet => sheet
    .getRange("a1:a10000")
    .createTextFinder("example.com/")
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .replaceAllWith("example2.com/")
  );
```

When you want to use the specific sheets, you can also use the following script.

```
var sheetNames = ["Sheet1","Sheet3",,,];  // Please set the sheet names.
SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheets()
  .forEach(sheet => {
    if (sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) {
      sheet
        .getRange("a1:a10000")
        .createTextFinder("example.com/")
        .useRegularExpression(true)
        .replaceAllWith("example2.com/")
    }
  });
```

### Added 2:

About your 2nd question of `Is there a way to replace all at once without the script visiting one sheet after another to make replacements? Because I think that's why it's delaying. I have 50 sheets. Perfect solution but if it would mass replace I think it would be even better?` [from your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64457738/how-to-replace-text-in-a-link-across-multiple-google-sheets-in-the-same-workbook/64457955?noredirect=1#comment113978940_64457955), in this case, I would like to propose to use Sheets API. When Sheets API is used, I think that the process cost will be able to be reduced.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const requests = ss.getSheets().map(s => ({
  findReplace:{
    find: "example.com/",
    searchByRegex: true,
    replacement: "example2.com/",
    range: {sheetId: s.getSheetId(), startRowIndex: 0, startColumnIndex: 0, endColumnIndex: 1}
  }
}));
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, ss.getId());
```

#### Note:

- If you will check all cells in all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet, I think that you can also use the following script.

  ```
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().createTextFinder("example.com/").useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith("example2.com/");
  ```

Comment: Yes, TextFinder is what I was looking for. How can I replace across multiple sheets and not just the current active sheet?

Comment: @mary ongubo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Is there a way to replace all at once without the script visiting one sheet after another to make replacements? Because I think that's why it's delaying. I have 50 sheets. Perfect solution but if it would mass replace I think it would be even better?

Comment: @mary ongubo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your 2nd question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?